# Help reconstructing two functions from their graphs

Tags: graphing-functions

I am reading the paper [PROPAGATOR: An Operational Cellular-Automata Based Wildfire Simulator](https://www.mdpi.com/2571-6255/3/3/26#), and there are some simple(ish) graphs here.  But there is no documentation of the equations used to create these graphs.  I emailed the original author, but no answer.  The first one is relatively simple, while the second one seems to be a bit more complicated.  How can I reconstuct the functions used to create these graphs?

## 1. $$  \alpha_h = f(slope) $$

[image]

Here I need alpha as a function of slope.  The flattness around s = 0 is not crucial, but a nice to have.  However, the asymptotes beginning around s = -50 and 50, occurring at alpha = -0.5 and 2 are fairly important.

## 2. $$ \alpha_w = f(speed_{wind}, direction_{wind}) $$

[image]

Obviously this one is a bit more involved.  I need alpha as a function of wind speed *and* direction.  While it involves 2 parameters, it seems that they are all variations on a theme of the bell curve, attenuated based on wind speed.

I'm a bit rusty in math and I'm not sure where to begin guessing at these formulas.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this will help anyone out specifically, but I spoke to a mathy friend and he helped me come up with some equations to approximate these graphs.

1. [$$0.5 + 0.75 * \frac{1}{e^{\frac{-x^{3}}{30000}} + 0.5}$$](https://www.google.com/search?q=plot+0.5+%2B+0.75*1%2F%28e%5E%28-%28x%5E3%29%2F30000%29%2B+0.5%29+from+-100+to+100&safe=off&sxsrf=ALeKk03_bceVJ_j5vxf7srrPhi8dvpf1RA%3A1623269507605&ei=gyDBYM6pJIml-wTk9IbACg&oq=plot+0.5+%2B+0.75*1%2F%28e%5E%28-%28x%5E3%29%2F30000%29%2B+0.5%29+from+-100+to+100&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANQmipY7TtghD9oAXACeACAAYIBiAHaBJIBAzYuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiO9_-SrovxAhWJ0p4KHWS6AagQ4dUDCA8&uact=5)

This came after the realization that the first graph goes like: [$$\frac{1}{e^x + 0.5}$$](https://www.google.com/search?q=plot+1%2F(e%5Ex+%2B+0.5)&oq=plot+1%2F(e%5Ex+%2B+0.5)&aqs=chrome..69i57.7146j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Playing with the constants, I am relatively close to graph 1, which is close enough for what I need.  In code:

```
const alphaSlope = (slope: number) => {
    return (
        0.5 + 0.75 * (1 / (Math.pow(Math.E, -Math.pow(slope, 3) / 30000) + 0.5))
    );
};
```

2. Each graph here is a bell curve, easily approximated by $$\frac{1}{e^{direction_{wind}^2}}$$

However, this is a 2 parameter function, with wind speed shaping the amplitude, width, and floor of the curve.  I found that the following coefficients work to get me close to the series of graphs in the figure:

$$(1 + 3*\frac{speed_{wind}}{100}) * \frac{1}{e^{(\frac{10^(speed_{wind}/100)}{100} * direction_{wind})^2}} + (1-\frac{speed_{wind}}{100})$$

Its a lot to look at in math format, but its more easily digested in code:

```
// javascript:

const alphaWind = (direction, speed) => {
    if (speed === 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    /**
     * Scaling factor, based on speed, helps determine bell amplitude and yShift
     */
    const s = speed / 100;
    /**
     * The 'floor' of the bell curve.  1 for speed = 0 km/h, drops to 0 for speed >= 100 km/h
     */
    const yShift = speed > 100 ? 1 - s : 0;
    /**
     * The amplitude of the curve. 1 for speed = 0 km/h, rises to 4+ for speed = 100 km/h
     */
    const amplitude = 1 + 3 * s;
    /**
     * The width of the bell curve, not at any specific height, determined by trial and error
     * Roughly 300 at speed = 0 km/h and 50-60 at speed = 100 km/h
     */
    const width = Math.pow(10, speed / 100) / 100;

    return amplitude / Math.pow(Math.E, (width * direction) ** 2) + yShift;
};
```